# Fetching photos from Picasa using GData in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm trying to get a photo thumbnail from the photo album present in Picasa account. I'm using Collection View for displaying the albums with a `UIImageView` inside the cells to display one of the photos from the album.

The problem is, sometimes when I run the code, the cells do not reflect the thumbnails and display a white background but when I put a breakpoint inside the datasource method-- `(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;` I can see the images getting set to the image view inside the cells and ultimately the photos on each cell after that.

I don't want to use `NStimer` to hold the Segue. Anyone having suggestions please...

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    GDataEntryPhotoAlbum *albumEntry = [app.albums objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if(app.albums.count>albumThumbnails.count)
    {
        [[GDataPhotoWrapper sharedGDataPhotoWrapperInstance] setDelegateGDataPhotoWrapper:self];
        [[GDataPhotoWrapper sharedGDataPhotoWrapperInstance] fetchImageForSelectedAlbum:albumEntry];

    }


    cell.backgroundView     =   [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"photo-frame.png"]];

    UILabel     *albumTitle =   (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:200];
    albumTitle.text         =   [[albumEntry title] stringValue];

    if(albumThumbnails.count==app.albums.count)
    {
        UIImageView *thumbnail = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
        thumbnail.image = (UIImage*)[albumThumbnails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }



    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code inside of çellForItemAtIndexPath ???

Comment: Hi Sachin.. I've edited the question with the code...